# javascript quicksort different output than expected

Tags: javascript, quicksort

I was learning quicksort and I wrote this code (half copied) but for some reason it doesn't work.  All I am trying to do is sort an array in ascending order using quicksort.

```
const arr = [5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 9, 5, 8, 7, 4];

const quickSort = (arr, left = 0, right = arr.length - 1) => {
    if (left < right) {
        let pivotIndex = pivot(arr, left, right)
        //LEFT HALF
        quickSort(arr, left, pivotIndex - 1);
        //RIGHT HALF
        quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Pivot function

```
const pivot = (arr, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) => {
    const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
    }

    let pivot = arr[start];
    let swapIndex = start;

    for (let i = 1; i < end; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) {
            swapIndex++;
            swap(arr, swapIndex, i);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, start, swapIndex)
    return swapIndex
}
```

Output

```
[
  1,         5,
  8,         7,
  undefined, undefined,
  9,         undefined,
  undefined, 2,
  2,         4,
  4,         5
]
```

Please tell me the error and the solution. I understand how quicksort works but still having some difficulty in understanding the logic of the code.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)` always iterates the entire array.

Comment: That still always starts from `1`, and your `end` is including. You'd need e.g. `for (let i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)`. I didn't check, whether there are more bugs, but fixing that at least sorts properly in the demo case.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in pivot is wrong.

Lets look at the first iteration of pivot:

```
start = 0;
end = 9;
pivot = 5;
swapIndex = 0;

i = 1;

if(arr[i] < pivot)
{
  swapIndex++;
  swap(arr, swapIndex, i)
}

// this evaluates to:

if(2 < 5)
{
  swapIndex = 1;
  swap(arr, swapIndex, 1);
}
```

So no swapping takes place.

Does the same happen for the next `i`?

```
if(4 < 5)
{
  swapIndex = 2;
  swap(arr, swapIndex, 2);
}
```

Yes, and the same happens for the next two `i`s. The next chance for a swap is at the end, when `i` would be 9, but the test is for `i < end`, so that swap never happens.

I believe it's more usual to pivot from the larger index, and only pivot from start to end.

```js
const pivot = (arr, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) => {
    const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
    };

    let pivot = arr[end];
    let swapIndex = start-1;

    for (let i = start; i <= end-1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) {
            swapIndex++;
            swap(arr, swapIndex, i);
        }
    }
    
    swap(arr, swapIndex+1, end)
    return swapIndex+1
}

let inp = [5, 2, 4, 2, 1, 9, 5, 8, 7, 4];

const quickSort = (arr, left = 0, right = arr.length - 1) => {
    if (left < right) {
        let pivotIndex = pivot(arr, left, right)
        //LEFT HALF
        quickSort(arr, left, pivotIndex-1);
        //RIGHT HALF
        quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, right);
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(quickSort(inp).join(','));
```